# using combination of select, union and group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by, union

I have two similar tables and a third table with one shared column (sms_status_id) with first and second table. I want to select similar columns from first and second table, union them with third table and then remove repetitive rows.
This is what I've done so far:

```
select *
from
(
    select sms_log_id, atm_id, device_id, error_id, datetime, retries, message
    from first_table
    join third_table
    on sms_log_id = sms_status_id
)
union
(
    select sms_id, atm_id, device_id, error_id, datetime, retries, message
    from second_table
    join third_table
    on sms_id = sms_status_id
 )
```

This gives me what I want but the result has repetitive rows. I tried to use

```
GROUP BY sms_status_id
```

but I didn't know where should I put it so didn't work out. Any suggestions??

This is w

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: A `UNION` always returns distinct rows, so you probably mean *multiple rows with the same sms_id*? Can you add some sample rows and explain why they are *repetitive*? What's you DBMS, based on the `GROUP BY` you seem to use mysql.

Comment: why dont use distinct?

Answer (score 0):

There is some error in your query.

Please see below code, if this will answer to your question.

@dnoeth is right, `UNION` always returns distinct rows otherwise use `UNION ALL`.

mytable1

```
sms_log_id     | Detail
1                a
1                b
1                c
```

mytable2

```
sms_id     | Detail
1            a
2            b
1            d
1            e
```

mytable3

```
id     | Status
1        Approve
2        Disapprove
```

Query:

```
SELECT t1.sms_log_id as t3_id, t1.Detail, t3.Status
FROM mytable1 as t1
LEFT JOIN mytable3 as t3
  ON t1.sms_log_id = t3.id

UNION

SELECT t2.sms_id as t3_id, t2.Detail, t3.Status
FROM mytable2 as t2
LEFT JOIN mytable3 as t3
  ON t2.sms_id = t3.id
```

Result:

```
t3_id   Detail  Status
1       a       Approve
1       b       Approve
1       c       Approve
2       b       Disapprove
1       d       Approve
1       e       Approve
```

you can't see in the result `a` from mytable2 because it is already in mytable1, and `b` is printed because it has different status.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec06/4)