# Why does select statement return distinct values from a table where there are duplicate results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting value in a table like this (SQL Server)

```
create table #t1 (id int)

insert into #t1(id)
   select 1 union
   select 2 union
   select 2 union
   select 1 

select * from #t1
```

But it gives me this data:

```
  id
-----
  1
  2
```

While I need data like:

```
  id
----
  1
  2
  2
  1
```

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: because you use UNION which implies a distinct

Comment: UNION removes duplicate entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answer this one to other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692678/using-combination-of-select-union-and-group-by/31695461#31695461)

`UNION` always returns distinct rows otherwise use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `union all` instead of `union`. `union all` allows redundant data to be selected:

```
create table #t1 (id int)

insert into #t1(id)
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 2 union all
select 1
```